# How many natural numbers less than $x$ fall in a certain residue class mod $q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $q$ be a fixed natural number. I am trying to understand why this statement is true (it's in a text I'm reading):

> The number of natural numbers $\le x$ that fall into a certain residue class$\mod q$ is at most $1+x/q$.

Comment: To see that your floor estimate is incorrect, note that the number of odd numbers $≤3$ is $2$, which is greater than $1.5$

Comment: @lulu i see, thanks. How would one explain that the correct estimate is $1+x/q$ though? I mean, why add 1 and not 2 for instance?

Comment: It's because $x/q$ rounds down.  Think about $x=21$ and $q=10$.  You have $1,11,21$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: The congruence class with the greatest number of elements $≤x$ is $1\pmod q$, assuming you do not allow $0$ as a natural number.  The representatives of that class would be $1, 1+q, 1+2q, \cdots, 1+kq$ where $k=\lfloor \frac {x-1}q\rfloor$  Thus the desired number is $1+\lfloor \frac {x-1}q\rfloor$.  If you allowed $0$ as a natural number, you'd get $1+\lfloor \frac xq\rfloor$.